# Как подключить движок WebKit к своему браузеру?

Tags: c#

Поискал в интернете, "как создать свой браузер на webkit" ничего толкового не выдал. Может вы что нибудь посоветуете?

Answer (score 1):

[Об использовании WebKit .NET](http://habrahabr.ru/post/154917/)